# Find and write to next blank cells in a column using App maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I need help with finding a number from a specific row in column A and write next to its blank cells in two different columns of the same row. e.g Find a number in COLUMN A2, Write to cells in COLUMN B2 and C2.

I have currently used filters and it hasn't helped.

```
function filterRange(filteredRange) {
    return filteredRange == [2.0];
}

function findCellByValue() {
    var ss = getSpreadSheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var range = values[i];
        var filtered = range.filter(filterRange);
        var newValue = filtered.concat(["Tee", "uhuuu"]);
        console.log(newValue);
        var ssheet = sheet.getRange("B2:C2");
        console.log(ssheet.setValues([newValue]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Appscript is apple script and not Google apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I have managed to find a workaround it though it is not the best possible solution but for this, it works.

```
   function findCellByValue(cellValue) {
    console.log(cellValue);
    var ss = getSpreadSheet().getActiveSheet();
    var range = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i ++)
    {

      if(range[i] == cellValue)
      {

       var Arrayvalues = range[i].concat(["test1","test2"]);
       ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,3).setValues([Arrayvalues]);
        i = range.length;
      }

}
```